# SharePoint get current user attribute

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, soap, caml

I have a page that needs to retrieve the department for the logged-in user.  Ideally I'd like to be able to do it through a JavaScript SOAP CAML query.  I have the user's id (which I'm assuming doubles as the GUID), so it seems like a simple matter of retrieving the row that matches the ID.

I'm looking into using the 'GetUserProfileByIndex' or 'GetUserProfileByGuid' function in SOAP, but I can't seem to find any solid documentation or decent examples using them.  I'm hoping to do something like this in JavaScript - (which isn't working):

```
 var userId = 194;
 "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
     <soapenv:Body> \
         <GetUserProfileByIndex  xmlns='http://microsoft.com/webservices/SharePointPortalServer/UserProfileService'> \
             <index>userId</index> \
         </GetUserProfileByIndex > \
     </soapenv:Body> \
 </soapenv:Envelope>";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you check out the jQuery Library for SharePoint 2007 and 2010 called SPServices. [$().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser) can retrieve the Department in an effecient 4 lines of code:

```
var thisDepartment = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
fieldName: "Department",
debug: false
});
```

Comment: I was looking at this jQuery library and this function, but it wouldn't work in my situation because: 1) I'm not using an account type that gives permission to view the profile page (although permission changes could fix this) 2) I'm actually pulling a 'department code' value from a column we added (which could probably be added to the profile page) and 3) the method it uses to retrieve the user profile information isn't as clean as I'd like - it works by loading the page and then '"scrapes" the values from the page based on the internal field name'.

Comment: @Eric That makes sense. I love your answer beacuse you show the brute force method that so many people tend to avoid. Yes, your code is many more lines, but it gets the job done!

Answer (score 3):

I've never answered my own question, but I managed to come up with a simple solution.  Here is how I went about it

1. When a user is logged in, there is a global JavaScript variable that includes that user's ID, - __spUserId
2. The user profile list is accessible via a CAML query through SOAP, it's titled 'User Information List'.
3. When accessing this list, you have to set the top-level site to point to _catalogs instead of Lists (or whatever it is exactly).  You do this by adding the element _catalogs \
4. Since it is accessing the user profile list as a list and not through a userprofile function, set the query type (?) to 'GetListItems'

Overall, here is the SOAP call and CAML query

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var soapEnv =
        "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
            <soapenv:Body> \
                <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
                    <listName>User Information List</listName> \
                    <topLevelSite>_catalogs</topLevelSite> \
                    <query> \
                        <Query> \
                            <Where> \
                                <Contains> \
                                    <FieldRef Name='ID' /> \
                                        <Value Type='Text'>"+_spUserId+"</Value> \
                                </Contains> \
                            </Where> \
                        </Query> \
                    </query> \
                    <viewFields> \
                        <ViewFields> \
                            <FieldRef Name='Name' /> \
                            <FieldRef Name='Department' /> \
                            <FieldRef Name='ID' /> \
                        </ViewFields> \
                    </viewFields> \
                    <query> \
                        <Query /> \
                    </query> \
                </GetListItems> \
            </soapenv:Body> \
        </soapenv:Envelope>";

    $.ajax({
        url: "/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapEnv,
        complete: processResult,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
    });
});
```

Comment: please mark this as an answer because its then easyer for others to find a solution to common problems. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use `GetUserProfileByName`, site collection ids can't be used to lookup anything in the user profile store.

http://amitkumarmca04.blogspot.com/2008/07/how-access-sharepoint-moss-user-profile.html